# Octave expands sliced arrays; Python does not

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'd like to do some Matlab/Octave index on Python, but I can't find equivalent code. Octave seems to expand sliced arrays, while Python does not. Please check the code below:

Octave:

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> xe = [1 1 2 3 3];
>> A(xe,:)
ans =
1   2   3
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
7   8   9
```

Python:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> aux = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
>>> A[aux,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-248-7ed394388336>", line 1, in <module>
A[aux,:]

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Tried also `numpy.take`:

```
>>> A.take(aux)
array([2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

How could I have the same result using Python? Thanks guys.

Comment: Before you do any more work in `numpy`, please read this guide that talks about transitioning to `numpy` from MATLAB: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users - One of the things it'll tell you is that Python is 0-indexed, which is your source of error.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, you keep saving me. In fact I solved that before getting an answer with you guys. Silly me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that in Python the index starts with 0 while in Matlab index starts with 1, so index 3 is out of bounds in your example

```
In [2]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [3]: aux = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])

In [4]: aux = aux - 1

In [5]: A[aux,:]
Out[5]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

`numpy.take` can also work, but you need to specify the axis, otherwise the flattened input array is used.

```
In [8]: A.take(aux, 0) # aux = array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
Out[8]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks @yangjie! I solved it before, but thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Python is 0 indexed, so change `aux` to `aux = np.array([0,0,1,2,2])` and it will work

Comment: Thanks dude, but @yangjie solved first. Thanks again.